# Insert default value to cell if value is blank/conditional format cell if value is blank

Tags: xlsxwriter

I have a situation where my dataframe can contain `None` for certain values that would normally be percent formatted.

I would like to use conditional formatting to find where the inserted value was `None` and update it to a specific string value, eg `'0.00%'`.

Is this possible, or should I instead be using internal python conditionals, eg `if val is None: val = '0.00%'`

Comment: for further detail:


```for row, term_summary in enumerate(summary_data_aggregate, start=2):
                for column, col_val in enumerate(term_summary.values()):
                    worksheet.write(row, column, col_val)
```
followed by 
```worksheet.set_column('P:P', 17, perc_format)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible, or should I instead be using internal python conditionals, eg if val is None: val = '0.00%'

No, it's not possible and yes you should be cleaning your data before or as you write it.

Specifically, it's not possible via xlsxwriter's conditional formatting. Conditional formatting is for applying [Format](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html)s to cells based on certain criteria. Line 1 of the [working with conditional formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html) in the docs.

However, if you do not want to do this programmatically you can achieve it using xlsxwriter's [write_formula](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_formula) function. For instance:

```
worksheet.write_formula(row, col, '=IF(ISBLANK(A1), "0.00%", A1)')
```

Where my A1 notation is replaced with yours.